# Embed XAML in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xaml, xsd

I'm developping a xml data format. Besides other data there should be a xaml drawing. So I wanted to have a xml element, which can contain any valid xaml. How can this be expressed in the XML Schema? I tried to import the xaml schema, but I couldn't find a xsd file for it. The makeshift would be to use an encoded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<![CDATA[ ... ]]` for storing the XAML. Afterwards you can obtain the schema by providing  a sample document to lots of freeware apps. Such apps are even web based.

Answer (score -1):

maybe, XMLProvider tag will help you.
this is sample XAML Code

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="BookData" XPath="/Books">
            <x:XData>
                <Books xmlns="">
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-0562-9" Stock="in">
                        <Title>XML in Action</Title>
                        <Summary>XML Web Technology</Summary>
                    </Book>
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-1370-2" Stock="in">
                        <Title>Programming Microsoft Windows With C#</Title>
                        <Summary>C# Programming using the .NET Framework</Summary>
                    </Book>
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-1288-9" Stock="out">
                        <Title>Inside C#</Title>
                        <Summary>C# Language Programming</Summary>
                    </Book>
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-1377-X" Stock="in">
                        <Title>Introducing Microsoft .NET</Title>
                        <Summary>Overview of .NET Technology</Summary>
                    </Book>
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-1448-2" Stock="out">
                        <Title>Microsoft C# Language Specifications</Title>
                        <Summary>The C# language definition</Summary>
                    </Book>
                </Books>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: The OP is not asking how to embed XML in XAML, but how to embed XAML in XML.